# Trying to create a mapping for Elasticsearch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a mapping for elasticsearch but I don't understand how to do it.
I am just trying to create this json with the XContentBuilder. I am using the Java API. I don't manage to create the nested objects. Nor do I know how much of this object the `putMapping` method actually needs.

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : "yes",
                "index" : "analyzed",
                "null_value" : "na"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best place to find answers for elasticsearch Java API questions is elasticsearch [integration tests](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/aaa3c48b3c105ed62acf5e7d2ad3a29866bbec13/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/test/integration/search/simple/SimpleSearchTests.java#L82). In your particular case, this is how this mapping will look like:

```
XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
    .startObject("tweet")
        .startObject("properties")
            .startObject("message")
                .field("type", "string")
                .field("store", "yes")
                .field("index", "analyzed")
                .field("null_value", "na")
            .endObject()
        .endObject()
    .endObject()
.endObject()
```

Comment: Oh, awesome, thanks! Do you normally specify all mappings yourself, or do you rely on the defaults when you are able to do that?